# comparing unix timestamps in python

Tags: python, time, unix-timestamp, duration

My application needs to compare the difference between two unix timestamps and return True or False. In summary, if the user has rated within a day or week of an attempted rating the function returns false. I fear this may not be very pythonic and that I may have re-invented the wheel. Is there a pre-packaged library in python 2.5 that will help me reach this same result in a better way?

```
import time

def is_allowed(time_rated, duration):
    durations={'day': 86400, 'week': 604800}
    if duration in durations and isinstance(time_rated, int):
        time_difference = int(time.time()) - time_rated
        if  time_difference > durations[duration]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return False
```

Comment: why do you evaluate `time_difference` when you don't use it? also, you can drop `else: return False`, since that's the default case.

Comment: Apologies, I edited my post slightly. I do use it. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are doing fine here, but you can just return the result of the `>` comparison, it already gives you a boolean value. There is also no need to turn the `time.time()` float to an integer here:

```
def is_allowed(time_rated, duration):
    durations = {'day': 86400, 'week': 604800}
    if duration in durations and isinstance(time_rated, int):
        time_difference = time.time() - time_rated
        return time_rated > durations[duration]
    return False
```

You can simplify this further by defaulting to a `duration` of `float('inf')`, saving you an `if` test:

```
def is_allowed(time_rated, duration):
    if not isinstance(time_rated, int):
        return False
    duration = {'day': 86400, 'week': 604800}.get(duration, float('inf'))
    return time.time() - time_rated > duration
```

This returns `False` if:

- `time_rated` is not an integer
- `duration` is not equal to `'day'` or `'week'` (because no number is ever greater than `float('inf')`).
- `time_rated` is less than 86400 or 604800 seconds ago, depending on `duration`.

Comment: can you expain to me why in the refactored piece of code (code block #2) `if isinstance(time_rated, int):  return False` is valid? At first glance it seems like that would return False if time_rated was a unix timestamp (e.g. 1394797042).

Comment: @user1645914: Your original version requires `isinstance(time_rated, int)` to be `True`. If it is not `True` then your `if` statement isn't matched and your function returns `False` instead. If `time_rated` can be a float, just remove the whole `if` statement altogether.

Comment: @user1645914: so, tl;dr: your code limited `time_rated` to an `int` *as well*. If you don't  want that, remove the test.

Comment: so the first code block with  `return time_rated > durations[duration]` instead of `return time_rated > durations[duration]:` works well. Correct me if I am wrong about the trailing colons. However, the second code block breaks [TypeError] if the user inputs `is_allowed('string','day')`.

Comment: @user1645914: Ah! I am not paying attention, it appears. Yes, the colon was an editing error, the second version was missing a crucial `not`. Mea Culpa, corrected.